# Parallel computing data extraction from a SQL database in Matlab

Tags: matlab, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing

In my current setup I have a for loop in which I extract different type of data from a SQL database hosted on Amazon EC2. This extraction is done in the function `extractData(variableName)`. After that the data gets parsed and stored as a mat file in `parsestoreData(data)`:

```
variables = {'A','B','C','D','E'}
for i = 1:length(variables)
    data = extractData(variables{i});
    parsestoreData(data);
end
```

I would like to parallelize this extraction and parsing of the data and to speed up the process. I argue that I could do this using a `parfor` instead of `for` in the above example.

However, I am worried that the extraction will not be improved as the SQL database will get slowed down when multiple requests are made on the same database.

I am therefore wondering if Matlab can handle this issue in a smart way, in terms of parralelization?

Comment: If you argue that `parfor` can do this, I presume you have already tried that. What were the conclusions? Was it faster? Was the SQL database slowed down?

Comment: I didn't try as I dont have the toolbox, so want to make a judgement before I spend money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workers in parallel pool running `parfor` are basically full MATLAB processes without a UI, and they default to running in "single computational thread" mode. I'm not sure whether `parfor` will benefit you in this case - the `parfor` loop simply arranges for the MATLAB workers to execute the iterations of your loop in parallel. You can estimate for yourself how well your problem will parallelise by launching multiple full desktop MATLABs, and set them off running your problem simultaneously. I would run something like this:

```
maxNumCompThreads(1);
while true
    t = tic();
    data = extractData(...);
    parsestoreData(data);
    toc(t)
end
```

and then check how the times reported by `toc` vary as the number of MATLAB clients varies. If the times remain constant, you could reasonably expect `parfor` to give you benefit (because it means the body can be parallelised effectively). If however, the times decrease significantly as you run more MATLAB clients, then it's almost certain that `parfor` would experience the same (relative) slow-down.

Comment: Clear logic, will try that to get an answer.